# Problem saving document remotely after ubuntu 19.04

Tags: libreoffice, file-sharing

After switching to disco dingo I am having trouble saving my spreadsheets on a windows 7 share on my network.

-I have tried remounting the share and reinstalling libreoffice (libreoffice Version: 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu2)

-I get two error messages, one after the other:

"Error saving the document XX: Nonexistent file"

"Error saving the document XX: General error. General input/output error."

-When I save the file locally and move it with nautilus there is no problem

If I'm missing info just let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what I found at ask.libreoffice.org, thanks erAck

> Probably [tdf#123472](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=123472), likely fixed in LibreOffice 6.2.4

And that version is scheduled for [Week 21 , May 20, 2019 - May 26, 2019](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleasePlan)

This is the first time I'll be really watching how quickly ubuntu repos are updated. Not being able to save texts and spreadsheets to smb shares - phew!